# How to run command in background

Tags: command-line, apt

I am using this command

```
sudo apt-get update && wget https://minergate.com/download/deb-cli && mv deb-cli minergate-cli-release.deb && sudo apt-get install -y gdebi && sudo gdebi minergate-cli-release.deb && screen minergate-cli -user someone@any.com --xmr
```

So first I need force yes; when prompted with "do you want to install software package?" y/n

I need to auto select y

Secondly I need to run this whole command in the background. It takes a long time to install.

Comment: FYI: 16.04 and newer, you don't need gdebi. apt will accept paths as arguments.

Answer (score 1):

append a "&" to your command ;)

Comment: Can i use "&" and "&&" in same command?

Comment: @Astril Yes, they're entirely different.  Note you need to append " &" - the space is important.

Answer (score 1):

1. By providing `-y` option with `apt-get` you can skip the confirmations while installing.
2. You can use the `screen` command to get in to a screen console in which you can perform long time installations so that you can detach and attach the screen as per you want.

   Type `apt-get install screen` in a terminal to install screen.

Once installed type `screen` in the terminal to get in to screen.

You can perform the commands in the screen.

Use key combinations `CTRL + A + D` to detach the screen and `CTRL +RX` to re-attach the screen if you have only one screen running(In this case only one screen is running)